# Limit of a series of functions as $0^+$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I want to show that
\begin{align*} \lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{1}{x\log x}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|\sin(nx)|}{n^2}=-1. \end{align*}"

Is this reasoning correct?
\begin{align*} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|\sin(nx)|}{n^2} & =\sum_{n\leqslant y}\frac{|\sin(nx)|}{n^2}+\sum_{n>y}\frac{|\sin(nx)|}{n^2}\\ & =(A)+(B) \end{align*}
with $ y=\frac{1}{x\sqrt{\log x^{-1}}}.$
\begin{align*} n\leqslant y\Rightarrow nx\leqslant \frac{1}{\sqrt{\log x^{-1}}}=o(1). \end{align*}
then \begin{align*} (A)& \sim x\sum_{n\leqslant y}\frac{1}{n}\sim x\log y\sim x\log x^{-1},\\\ 
(B)&\leqslant \sum_{n>y}\frac{1}{n^2}\sim x\sqrt{\log x^{-1}}=o(A). \end{align*}
We conclude \begin{align*} \lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{1}{x\log x}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|\sin(nx)|}{n^2}=-1. \end{align*}

Comment: Thank you, But if I take $y=\frac 1{\sqrt x}$, using the same reasoning, I find that $A\sim -\frac{1}{2}x \ln(x)$. There is something wrong with the reasoning

Comment: If you take $y=1/\sqrt x,$ you cannot use the same reasoning because then, $B\ne o(A).$

Comment: i delette my comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea works, but you have to be careful with the $\sim$, because you are summing a number of things that depends on $x$.

This is a way of making it rigurous. We start with $\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left|{#1}\right|}\newcommand{\bp}[1]{{\left({#1}\right)}}\let\leq=\leqslant\let\geq=\geqslant \abs{\sin x} = x + O(x^3)$ for $x\geq0$, which we can easily prove. So, we get
$$\begin{aligned}
\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{\abs{\sin(nx)}}{n^2}
&= \sum_{n\leq y} \frac{\abs{\sin(nx)}}{n^2} + \sum_{n>y} \frac{\abs{\sin(nx)}}{n^2} \\
&= \sum_{n\leq y} \frac{nx + O(n^3x^3)}{n^2} + O\bp{\sum_{n>y} \frac1{n^2}} \\
&= x \sum_{n\leq y} \frac1n + O\bp{x^3 \sum_{n\leq y} n} + O\bp{\frac1y} \\
&= x \bp{\log y + O(1)} + O\bp{x^3y^2 + \frac1y}.
\end{aligned}$$
Note that in the third line we used that the constant in $O(n^3x^3)$ is the same for each term. Now we take $y = \frac1x$ (chosen to minimize the error term), and we get
$$\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{\abs{\sin(nx)}}{n^2} = x(-{\log x} + O(1)) + O(x) = -x\log x + O(x).$$
Therefore
$$\frac{1}{x\log x} \sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{\abs{\sin(nx)}}{n^2} = -1 + O\bp{\frac1{\abs{\log x}}}$$
and taking $x\to0^+$ we get the result.

Comment: There is still something I don't understand. If you take $y=1/\sqrt{x}$, we conclude that $\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{\abs {\sin(nx)}}{n^2} = -\frac 12 x\log x + xO(1)) + O(x²+x))$, but $xO(1)) + O(x²+x) \to 0$. Therefore, we have $\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{\abs {\sin(nx)}}{n^2} \sim -\frac 12 x\log x$.

Comment: Hmm no. When $y = 1/\sqrt{x}$ we get $\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{|\sin(nx)|}{n^2} = -\frac12x\log x + O(x) + O(x^2 + \sqrt{x}) = -\frac12x\log x + O(\sqrt{x})$. When you divide by $x\log x$ the error doesn't go away.

Comment: Ok perfect, thank